# Create a default AVD with maven?

Tags: android, maven

is it possible to create an Android Virtual Device with Maven? Because right now one has to create an AVD manually before running the maven build with instrumentation tests.

I [searched the web](https://startpage.com/do/search?q=maven%20android%20create%20avd&l=english), but could find any information. The [android-maven-plugin](http://maven-android-plugin-m2site.googlecode.com/svn/plugin-info.html) isn't able to do it.

Comment: Short answer is YES, anything scriptable is mavenable, check out [Managing AVDs from the Command Line](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Thanks to yorkw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979661/create-a-default-avd-with-maven#comment26292925_17979661), I found a solution.

Note:

- The ant task works only for windows, but could easily be adjusted for other OS.
- The chosen Android target is important, because some targets require user interaction to create an AVD:

> [Managing AVDs from the Command Line](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html): "If the target you selected
>   was a standard Android system image ("Type: platform"), the android
>   tool next asks you whether you want to create a custom hardware
>   profile."

---

pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <exec executable="cmd.exe">
                        <arg value='/c ${env.ANDROID_HOME}\tools\android create avd --name myDefaultAVD --target "Google Inc.:Google APIs:10" --force'/>
                    </exec>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>createDefaultAVD</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```